# Signup with Azure AD B2C using phone number

Tags: flutter, azure-ad-b2c, azure-authentication

In my mobile application I will be just using phone number for anthentication. Right now I am trying this with Postman which works, which means the user is created, but a code is not sent to the user. I want the user to receive a code when signing up and signing in. I wont be using user flows as I wish to use a custom sign up page for my app. I tested it with user flows and was able to get a code on my mobile device.

Here is my Postman POST request to https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users

```
{
"accountEnabled": true,
"displayName": "Test Name",
"identities": [
{
"signInType": "phoneNumber",
"issuer": "testorg.onmicrosoft.com",
"issuerAssignedId": "+1 416-000-0000"
}
],
"mobilePhone": "+1 416 000 000",
"passwordPolicies": "DisablePasswordExpiration",
"passwordProfile": {
"password": "82510f31-1c89-d103-73c8-9fbedda45dcc",
"forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": false
}
}
```

Please advise!

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/signup-signin-with-phone-number) for a custom policy that allows sign-up via phone.